# Why does the LIKE[c] in my subquery predicate not match this name?

Tags: iphone, core-data, nspredicate

I have two entities: Department and DepartmentInfo. Every Department has one or many DepartmentInfo Objects. Inside DepartmentInfo, there is an departmentName attribute.

I want to fetch all those Department objects which have a specific departmentName. So I make an NSFetchRequest for the Department entity, and use this fetch request:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(departmentName, $s, $s.departmentName LIKE[c] %@).@count > 0", @"Marketing"];
```

It works, BUT: The LIKE[c] doesn't! I must match against the exact department name. If I do this, I will get no match:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(departmentName, $s, $s.departmentName LIKE[c] %@).@count > 0", @"Mar"];
```

What could be wrong here?

Comment: Use @"Mar*" and you will match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Jason Coco didn't post this as answer, I do it:

> Use @"Mar*" and you will match

Answer (score 0):

The use of `SUBQUERY` here is unnecessary.  You can achieve the same results using:

```
ANY departmentInfo.departmentName LIKE[c] 'Mar*'
```

Execute that against an array of `Department` objects and it'll work.